# how to import multiple csv files that are named by year and month and some other different characters in matlab?

Tags: matlab, csv

I have some csv files that are named as:

```
eddypro_CFCT_201206_full_output_2013-06-26T121839.csv
eddypro_CFCT_201207_full_output_2013-06-26T160648.csv
.....
```

The files are mainly sorted by year and month. The characters after `output` are only some random numbers and letters, but the length will be same all the time.

Is there a way that i can import all these `csv` files together in `matlab`?

Part of my old code like this that can only read the files named as: `eddypro_CFCT_01_full_output.csv`, `eddypro_CFCT_02_full_output.csv`, and so on.

```
EddyproPath = 'C:\Users\CFCT_test\'; 
numfiles = length(dir([EddyproPath '\*.csv'])); 
for n = 1:numfiles   
FilePath = [EddyproPath,'eddypro_CFCT_',num2str(n,'%02d'),'_full_output.csv'];
fid = fopen (FilePath, 'rt');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using `dir` to get the number of files, so why not use `dir` to get the file list.  Or am I misunderstanding?

```
d = dir([EddyproPath '\*.csv']);
for ii=1:numel(d),
    fid = fopen(fullfile(EddyproPath,d(ii).name),'rt');
    % ...
end
```

If for whatever reason `dir` is not dictionary sorting the file names, you can do `sort({d.name})`.

Comment: Great.  I'm glad the answer was useful.  ^  ;)